# Angular - NodeJS - during Azure DevOps build, I need to increase max-old-space-size each day to avoid Javascript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, angular, azure-devops

On Azure DevOps during my build pipeline, one step build my Angular app with this command :

```
ng build --prod
```

As a result, I received the message :

> EXEC : FATAL error : Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - Javascript heap out of memory

I added a step in my build pipeline to increase the max-old-space-size.

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   Write-Host "SET NODE_OPTIONS"
   
  displayName: 'Set NODE_OPTIONS'
  env:
    NODE_OPTIONS: --max-old_space-size=6144
```

It's working after that **but I need to increase the max-old-space-size size each day of 1gb**

- day 1: 4096mb
- day 2: 5120mb
- day 3: 6144mb
- ...

Something doesn't work well.  How to debug this type of leak happening during the build ?  When I execute my build locally the max-old-space-size doesn't need to be has big.

---

Version use on the server :

```
Angular 10.2.5
Node.JS 10.23.0
```

I can't upgrade my Node.JS version because there is others applications on the server who use this version of Node.JS .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using local server to build your project in Azure Pipeline, NPM cache can increase memory usage day by day.

You can add the command: `npm cache clean --force` to pipeline to clean the npm cache.

And you can add the argument: `--optimize-for-size`  before ng build --prod to optimize memory.

For example:

```
npm cache clean --force && node --max_old_space_size=8192 --optimize-for-size node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```